# jQuery - Get HTTP request doesn't execute JavaScript in fetched source

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to create a Chrome plug-in that fetches a webpage from a given URL and scrapes it's HTML content to find a download link to a video. The problem is that the fetched webpage runs some JavaScript to generate download links on the page. However, when I fetch the page using below jQuery code, I don't see the download URL as (possibly) the JavaScript on the fetched page hasn't executed.

```
$.get(link, function(response) {
    console.log($response);
    //console.log($(response).find(".videoData").attr("value"));
});
```

I looked online and got to know that jQuery's .load() function will also fail in this case. PhantomJS's page.open() function seems to do what I require, but I want to deploy some lightweight solution inside my Chrome extension, so I am unable to use PhantomJS.

Comment: so you want the source code of the page after a certain js generates the links?

Comment: yes, after all the JavaScript code has finished execution on the given url, I would like to fetch its source html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in the web page you're trying to scrape. Make sure that you enter "document_end" in the manifest so you can ensure that your script executes **after** the target page has finished loading.

Another solution would be to create an invisible `iframe` within which you'd load the target url, and then scrape the loaded code for the `video` links.

Comment: Brilliant! The second solution with iframe loading works great. But there is one problem, the newly inserted page takes a few seconds to load the video url. Is it possible to know when the loading has finished inside the newly populated iframe?

Comment: I tried timeouts. But it appears that I can't access the contents inside the iframe from my JavaScript code. Even though I can see them in the 'Inspect' view in Chrome. :(

Comment: I added a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144418/cant-scrape-elements-inside-document-element

Comment: Glad it worked @sircasms! I answered your other question too