# Can't scrape elements inside #document element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, web-scraping

For one of my Chrome extension project, I fetched the HTML content of another webpage in an `<iframe>` tag of the current webpage, by populating its src attribute dynamically. Now, I want to scrape a few values from inside the `<iframe>` tag. But the jQuery always shows this `<iframe>` tag as empty. The reason I am using  is that there are a few JavaScript files inside the fetched page that I want to get executed before I start scraping. I also tried to set wait timers, but jQuery always shows `<iframe>` tag to be empty (though the src attribute is set).

Upon investigation, I found that the `<iframe>` has a strange `#document` value inside it, followed by the normal HTML tags. I wonder if this is the reason why the jQuery is unable to recurse through a DOM hierarchy inside the `<iframe>` tag.

See below screenshot of the "inspect" view of the desired `<iframe>` tag.

[image]

Also, the main webpage on which the `<iframe>` tag exists is on the same website as the newly fetch page url (albeit a different subdomain). And I'm not getting any access permission warnings in Chrome, so I do not suspect this to be a cross-domain issue.

**Edit:**
Even after 10 seconds wait:

```
console.log($("#insertHere").text());
```

returns empty. And,

```
console.log($("#insertHere").parent().html());
```

returns: `<iframe id="insertHere" src="/courses/intro..." style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You can grab iframe content with such code :

```
$('#insertHere').contents().find("html").html();


$('#insertHere').contents().find("#MathJax_Message").text();
```

If the iframe is on another domain (seems to not be in your case), cross-site-scripting (XSS) protection of your browser will block it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the $('#insertHere').contents() is also empty. And, I see no warning from Chrome about XSS. (Though the website that the "Content Script" of the plug-in fetches, redirects to a sub-domain of the current website.)

Comment: Can you do a test and see if you iframe can access to the main parent page (if you have control in the iframe page you are loading) ?

Comment: Otherwise, there is a good way to make commmunicate 2 pages from different domains : you can use online services like "pusher", that will establish a channel between the pages...here you are limited at all with domains/subdomains. I can give you working code if this interests you. Obviously you need to be able to add pusher code in the iframe content you want to scrape

Comment: I tried to access the parent page from within the iframe and I got this error: "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame". So, it appears that the subdomain of same website is being considered as cross-origin case. I tested with dig command, and I am getting different IP addresses for domain and subdomain. So, that could be the reason for the failure.

Comment: that sounds very interesting. Please share the code. :)

Comment: OK, I give it to you in some hours (midnight in France...), you can already create pusher.com free account, and test their console..

Answer (score 0):

The `#document` is a page document object for the iFrame DOM.

Try accessing the `document` of the iframe, e.g.

```
var frame = document.getElementById('#hidden-frame');
console.log(frame.document.body);
```

You could also try using a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and allowing it in [all pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)  with `<all_urls>`, which should be loaded with the iframe content, and use it to send the content to `background script` using messaging.